# Delete dialog box with ajax - Symfony 3

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have a basket where I can have items that I can delete

[image]

When I click on the bin icon, it delete it straight from the page with this script

```
$('.delete').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ path('ajax_app_basket_bill_delete_item') }}',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'itemId': value
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#item' + value).remove();
                    if (data['success'] == 1) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ path('ajax_app_basket_bill_refresh_price') }}',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                'credit_box' : creditBox,
                                'code' : code
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#t1').text(data['totalWithoutTax']);
                                $('#t2').text(data['tax']);
                                $('#t3').text(data['total']);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

(here is the html in case you need to see this)

```
<a class="delete" data-value="{{ item.id }}" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a>
```

And my question is, how can I actually create a very simple dialog box to confirm deletion when I click on the bin icon without to remove it instantly.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way would be with the javascript function [confirm](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp):

```
$('.delete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Really delete this item?')){
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('ajax_app_basket_bill_delete_item') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'itemId': value
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#item' + value).remove();
                if (data['success'] == 1) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ path('ajax_app_basket_bill_refresh_price') }}',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            'credit_box' : creditBox,
                            'code' : code
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#t1').text(data['totalWithoutTax']);
                            $('#t2').text(data['tax']);
                            $('#t3').text(data['total']);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can get more fancy with jQueryUI's [.dialog()](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or other additional dialog box scripts easily foundable via Google or else.

Comment: Thank you it works! :) But there a little issue with its kind of box. There is a checkbox with it that says "do you want to prevent other pop ups like this? and if I check it then when I click on the bin, no more box and delete can be done.... :(

Comment: And do you know how to center it in the middle of the screen ?

Comment: Use a fancier dialog box like the one linked at the end of my answer, or other like [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com/), an abstraction around bootstrap modal. (There are a lot of them)

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you